# npm update packages recursively

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-shrinkwrap

I have a project like this
[image]

I want to update all private_mod version (root and nested levels) to 1.3.2. Is there a npm way to do so?

Note: Each dependecy (dep-1, dep-2, dep-3) have their own `package.json`

One way that I can think of doing is:
- generate shrinkwrap file `npm shrinkwrap`
- Manually edit `npm-sharinkwrap.json` file for newer version of private_mod for all dependencies
- Do npm install again to install new packages off the `shrinkwrap` file

Comment: What is your motivation for this? Messing with dependencies' dependencies is almost always a bad idea. There's probably a good reason "dep-3" specifies the version of lodash that it does (this is actually a good example because there are breaking changes between lodash 1.3 and 3.x). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have updated the question. I know upgrading from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2 will not break any dependency. So in this case how can I upgrade the private_mod to be consistent in my App project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update), try

```
npm --depth 9999 update private_mod@version
```

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't available at the time of posting the questions.

Comment: That "--depth" is not necessary anymore/not working anymore according to https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0019-remove-update-depth-option.md